# Disable scientific notation in t_test of rstatix package

Tags: r, t-test

I want to use to following exampe to do t-tests with multiple variables - The code is used from https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-perform-multiple-t-test-in-r-for-different-variables/:

```
options(scipen = 99)

# Load required R packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

# Prepare the data and inspect a random sample of the data
mydata <- iris %>%
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
  as_tibble()
mydata %>% sample_n(6)

# Transform the data into long format
# Put all variables in the same column except `Species`, the grouping variable
mydata.long <- mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, names_to = "variables", values_to = "value")
mydata.long %>% sample_n(6)

stat.test <- mydata.long %>%
  group_by(variables) %>%
  t_test(value ~ Species) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "BH") %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test
```

This tutorial uses the t_test function of the rstatix package. It works great, but is there a way to disable the scientific notation of the p-values? I want to output p-values like 0.000445 instead of 4.45e-4.

Unfortunetely the use of

```
options(scipen = 99)
```

did not change anything.

Thank you!

**EDIT: The solution can be found in the comments** - it is necessary to call stat.test this way:

```
as.data.frame(stat.test)
```

Thank rawr for his comment!

Comment: Run `options(scipen = 99)` in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that: this does not change the output of t_test.

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I posted the code - it is just the snippets from the website mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: `as.data.frame(stat.test)` would work for your example

Comment: It works, great - thank you!